# mod_rewrite weird problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a strange problem with mod_rewrite, the rules that are relevant here are:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/igre\-(.*)\.php\?Page=([0-9]+)$ game.php?GameUrl=$2&Page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/igre\-(.*)\.php$ game.php?GameUrl=$2&Page=1 [L]
```

And a corresponding URL might look something like this:

```
example.com/miselne-igre/igre-shirk.php?Page=2
example.com/miselne-igre/igre-shirk.php
```

The problem is that the first rule has no effect. If I use the first URL from the example I always get 1 into the Page variable, which shows that the second rule is used.
So what's wrong with the first one? And why is the second rule even matching a URL with ".php?Page=XYZ" at the end, if I said that the URL ends with ".php"?

ps: other rules in the .htaccess file are working fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string is not part of the URI path that is being processed by the [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). You have to use the [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to process the query string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Page=[0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/igre-([^/]+)\.php$ game.php?GameUrl=$1&%0 [L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/igre-([^/]+)\.php$ game.php?GameUrl=$1&Page=1 [L]
```

---

But you can still simplify this by using the QSA flag (*query string append*):

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/igre-([^/]+)\.php$ game.php?GameUrl=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I didn't know about that. I guess I never used a rewrite that would rewrite the query part.

Thank you very much for your ultra quick solution!

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite is not using the query in it's rewriting process. Therefor you first RewriteRule is ignored. You could combine it with a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) (haven't tested it though) like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/igre\-(.*)\.php\?Page=([0-9]+)$ game.php?GameUrl=$2 [L, qsappend]
# qsappend appends the original query, in this case (Page=xx)
```

Ah, like Gumbo said; you can also use `%1` to back reference to the page numer.

Answer (score -1):

Is it just me or are your arguments back-to-front?

Do you mean:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\-igre\.php\?Page=([0-9]+)$ game.php?GameUrl=$2&Page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\-igre\.php$ game.php?GameUrl=$2&Page=1 [L]
```

You wanted to match `miselne-igre` not `igre-miselne`.

Obviously this doesn't address the main issue, but thought I'd throw that in.

Dom

Comment: In the given example I'm only interested in the "shirk" part. So my rewrite is OK regarding that :)

Comment: I also got caught by that at first, but he doesn't catch the path, but the filename and the slash at it's beginning ("/igre"), slash has to be escaped, so it is '\/igre'